# How to make pandoc stop omitting equations when rendering to PowerPoint?

Tags: latex, powerpoint, pandoc

I have a presentation written in MarkDown that I have to render to PowerPoint.  Rendering as Beamer pdf output, everything works fine.  But when I try to output to PowerPoint, all equations are either broken or missing.  In various iterations, sometimes an occasional equation will render; I have not tracked exactly what enables that.

While I don't expect the rendering to PowerPoint to preserve all of my syntax, in the past this worked without too much fuss.  What could be happening that causes Pandoc/powerpoint to ignore equations?

Alternatively, is there a straightforward way to rerender the equations as images and embed them?  I have enough math in my actual presentation that I'd rather not do this manually.  I've read about `--webtex`, but that doesn't seem to apply to Office formats.  And I found an old Haskell library claiming to do such a thing locally, but trying to install it was a deadend.

Here's a minimal example presentation in MarkDown for which I'm seeing issues.  In particular, I want to be able to display equations with varying color.  `\textcolor` may not work, so I tried `\color` as well, but all of those equations get shown in raw TeX form, while the others disappear.

```
---
title: dumb.md
...

# Just a test

* Basic math $\Gamma(4)$
* Color Math ${\color{red}\pi}$
* TextColor Math $\textcolor{red}{\pi}$
* Display math:

$$
\Sigma(4)
$$

# Next frame, colored display

$$
{\color{blue}\Sigma(4)}
$$
```

Running `pandoc dumb.md -o dumb.pptx`, however, reveals equations that were not rendered as raw TeX (i.e. those using color) are entirely missing.  I get some warnings, but even removing the offending lines, pandoc swallows the rest of the math.

```
[WARNING] Could not convert TeX math '{\color{red}\pi}', rendering as TeX:
  {\color{red}\pi}
         ^
  unexpected "{"
  expecting "%", "\\label", "\\nonumber" or whitespace
[WARNING] Could not convert TeX math '\textcolor{red}{\pi}', rendering as TeX:
  \textcolor{red}{\pi}
            ^
  unexpected "{"
  expecting "%", "\\label", "\\nonumber" or whitespace
[WARNING] Could not convert TeX math '
  {\color{blue}\Sigma(4)}
  ', rendering as TeX:
  
         ^
  unexpected "{"
  expecting "%", "\\label", "\\nonumber" or whitespace
```

I'm using `pandoc 2.11.1.1 Compiled with pandoc-types 1.22, texmath 0.12.0.3, skylighting 0.10.0.3, citeproc 0.1.1.1, ipynb 0.1.0.1`.  I don't actually have a local copy of PowerPoint, so I've been using SOffice to sanity check.  Online Office365, however, gives me similar results.